# Xcode 7 crashes when I change schemes

Tags: xcode

I have about 8 schemes in my workspace. Everything was working fine, but this morning when I tried to change schemes Xcode crashed immediately. Based on other posts I tried running `defaults delete com.apple.t.Xcode` but this did not help. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 6):

In the Finder, control-click on your .xcworkspace file and choose Show Package Contents. In `xcuserdata/tony.xcuserdatad` you will see a file called `UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate`. Delete that file and then re-open Xcode. All will be good. It seems like that file was corrupted and Xcode crashed when trying to read from it.

Comment: Didn't work for me. It always crashes. Don't even show the crash log. My Xcode version is 7.3.0

Comment: I guess you are running into a different problem. The first thing I would try is a fresh pull of your code to see if that fixes the issue.